# Ubuntu16.04 - After installing Jupyter notebook it does not start and gives an error

Tags: python, installation, jupyter, ubuntu-16.04

I searched a lot but I can't find an answer!
I am trying to install jupyter as I usually do. But for 3 days it has not worked!

When I install it with the following commands:

```
spark@spark-VirtualBox:~$  sudo apt install python3-pip
spark@spark-VirtualBox:~$  pip3 install jupyter
```

I run my jupyter notebook with:

```
spark@spark-VirtualBox:~$ jupyter notebook
```

And I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 14, in <module>
    from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import traitlets
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1779
    return repr(f'{value.__module__}.{value.__name__}')
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you help me please!
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to install a newer version of python, or an older version of jupyter. The version you are installing doesn't appear to support python 3.5. That version of Ubuntu will be EOL in less than a year.

Comment: [f-strings were introduced in python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), so you will need at least python 3.6. Ubuntu 16.04 installs python 3.5.2. You can look into virtual environment solutions, like `venv`, `virtualenv`, and `conda`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried upgrading to python 3.6 but it doesn't work!
Not possible to go down in jupyter version!